# Preserve custom blocks with YUI Compressor

Tags: javascript, minify, yui-compressor

I am using [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) to minify Javascript files. However these Javascript files contains some custom content (embedded JSP tags) that I would need YUI Compressor to ignore. I am looking for something similar to the "custom preservation rules" in [htmlcompressor](http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/#Creating_your_own_block_preservation_rules).

Does anyone know whether this can be done with YUI Compressor? If not, can anyone suggest an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using JSP to generate javascript, then compress the output of the JSP script, rather than before.

If you can't, you should split off the javascript that is static, and serve the dynamic javascript separately.

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks. However the first approach is not feasible. Second approach would work of course but it requires a major rewrite.

Comment: If you think you need to dynamically generate and compress large javascript files, I think you may be doing the wrong thing. If you're looking for a workaround, just put some placeholders in place of the JSP tags and replace it after compression. You have to make sure whatever your placeholder is, also ends up in teh final output.. so it could be some kind of string for instance.

Comment: I am not actually generating the javascript dynamically, however my use case is a bit complex and not really worth getting into. The placeholders idea is interesting, though.

Comment: Well you are certainly generating part of your JS dynamically, otherwise you wouldn't need JSP right?

Answer (score 4):

From the [YUI compressor docs](https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/blob/master/doc/README), you might be able to do this using "hints":

```
+ It is possible to prevent a local variable, nested function or function
argument from being obfuscated by using "hints". A hint is a string that
is located at the very beginning of a function body like so:

function fn (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    "arg2:nomunge, localVar:nomunge, nestedFn:nomunge";

    ...
    var localVar;
    ...

    function nestedFn () {
        ....
    }

    ...
}
```

In your case, you could add a nested function and use the "nomunge" hint for that function.

Comment: Good idea, haven't thought about this. Unfortunately it does not work. The actual problem is that YUI Compressor tries to parse the Javascript file and fails because the code is not syntactically correct (due to the embedded JSP tag). What I need is a way to tell YUI to just 'ignore' the JSP tag while parsing...

Comment: Couldn't you just extract those troublesome parts to another JS and not compress it ? That would be the simplest solution I can think of without changing your process too much.